# Double not parsing correctly when high enough

Tags: c#, double, exponential

I have a visitors count in my website and I'm trying to save it as `Double` instead of `Integer` because it allows higher numbers.

The thing is that when the count is too high, for instance `300,000,000,000,000,000,000,000`, it gets saved as `3.0E+23`.

How can I possibly parse this number to it's long, regular format?
I was trying some things with `double.TryParse` method, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why don't use `long` aka `System.Int64` ? Btw you said it is saved as `3.0E+23` but where?

Comment: Floating point numbers aren't precise (even for integers!) after a _threshold_. Point is: why you're using a f.p. for a counter? Isn't Long big enough???

Comment: And if Long isn't big enough for you, there's always ulong (twice the size for the same storage space). Seems like a very successful website :-)

Comment: You can even use the unsigned long (ulong), which take a range from 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 and is precise

Comment: I read BigInteger has no limit. Can it be used instead and will store exact value?

Comment: `int` is enough for your website's visitor count. It is capable of holding ~2Billion. You don't even need long. BigInterger is just overkill. If you need more than int, use long or ulong.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait - Doubles should never ever be used as a counter, and no, you don't need BigInteger. Also, 300,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 and 3.0E+23 are two ways to write exactly the same number.

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff I want to write the long format of the number, which is `300,000,000,000,000,000,000,000` and it's being saved as `3.0E+24`.

Comment: @Omer Aviv `String.format("{0:F0}", myAbsolutelyUnnecessaryDoubleCounter)`

Comment: Fir the visitors count should be enough `unsigned int`. If you have something other in mind and get to *that* big numbers, who exceed limits of even `unsigned long`, `BigInt` is your only option.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will use `ulong`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible, as looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) double only stores 15 to 16 digits so it will revert to the short format if the number is larger than that. On the other hand [ulong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx) is 64 bits and contain a much larger number accurately, and if that is not enough, there is the [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class, however you can't save this in the database, as it is not supported (BigInt maps to long).